# Redirect and rewrite my URLs with an .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Redirect and rewrite my **URLs** with an **.htaccess** file?

Duplicate content, 2 links with the same content.

`https://www.pooeen.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30`

Please be redirected to the **URL** below

`https://www.pooeen.com/viewtopic.php?t=30`

I am looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Thank you in advance for invaluable co-operation.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules.

```
RewriteEngine ON

##Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(viewtopic\.php)\?f=(?:[^&]*)&(t=\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanking you for your kind co-operation.
With my best wishes of success and prosperity.

Comment: @POURYA.RAOUFI, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.